# How do I skip a folder during rsync?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, rsync, scp

```
rsync -r -a -v -e ssh --delete /home/user/project user@ip:/home/user/
```

Right now, this is my command.

What if I want to skip the folder `/home/user/project/src/node_modules/jquery` ? I don't want that copied over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--exclude /project/src/node_modules/jquery
```

Comment: Still rsyncs or doesn't delete? Because, I believe there's a `--delete-excluded` or some such option for it, check the man page.